# find selected value of dropdown in every row of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

There are multiple rows in a table being created using `ng-repeat`. Each row has a dropdownlist. I want to get the selected value in a dropdown and attach that value with other corresponding values in the row in a string format using JavaScript or JQuery on click of Next button. eg:"one,B:two,B:three,A:four:C" (here in this example assuming B is selected for dropdown in first row,similar logic for other rows)

The below is the HTML snippet:

```
<div class="mainDiv" ng-controller="myController">                                          
    <div class="div1">
        <table class="table myTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <center>serial</center>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <center>data</center>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <center>aplhabet</center>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="myTableBody">
                <tr ng-repeat="data in myData" id="{{$parent.$id+'-'+$index}}">
                    <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
                    <td>{{data}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <select>
                            <option value="Select">-- Select --</option>
                            <option value="A">A</option>
                            <option value="B">B</option>
                            <option value="C">C</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-primary btnNext">Next</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

and below is the angularJS part:

```
myApp.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.myData = ["one","two","three","four"];
});
```

Comment: need {{data}},selected value of dropdown of each row. for example in a table
serial     data alphabet
1 one            B
2 two           B
3 three C
4 four         A


expected outcome: "one,B:two,B:three,A:four:C"

Answer (score 1):

Add an `ng-model={ selectData[data] }`

Then update the controller with the following

```
$scope.selectData = {}
getResults= function() {
  var returnData = $scope.myData.map(function(data) {
    return data + ',' + $scope.selectData[data];
  });
  return returnData.join(':');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch to an object.

```
$scope.myData = {
    one: {
        id: 'one',
        value: null
    }, 
    two: {
        id: 'two',
        value: null
    }, 
    three: {
        id: 'three',
        value: null
    }, 
    four: {
        id: 'four',
        value: null
    }
}
```

In your HTML, add an `ng-model` to your select

```
<select ng-model="data.value">
    <!-- your options, because I'm lazy -->
</select>
```

You will get an object containing all you want. In my opinion, I find it easier to work with objects rather than arrays.